# How to generate a reasonably sized memory dump file of a .NET Core process on linux?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, coreclr

I'm trying to generate a **reasonably sized** core dump of a running .net core process using `gcore`, but the file is larger than 20GB.
The process is `dotnet wapi.dll` which is the binary of an empty project created using `dotnet new webapi`.
I think size of the dump is related to amount of virtual memory.

[image: htop]

The main question is how can I generate a smaller core dump?

Is this related to what I'm thinking of (virtual memory)?

Should I limit the virtual memory? how?

Comment: Take a look for "-f" flags: https://people.redhat.com/anderson/extensions/gcore_help_gcore.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the easiest way to do this is to use `createdump` utility which comes with dotnet runtime and is located in the same directory as libcoreclr.so. ([thanks to Maoni Stephens](https://twitter.com/maoni0/status/1179649416417832960?s=20)).

Using `createdump` is pretty easy:

```
createdump [options] pid
-f, --name - dump path and file name. The pid can be placed in the name with %d. The default is "/tmp/coredump.%d"
-n, --normal - create minidump (default).
-h, --withheap - create minidump with heap.
-t, --triage - create triage minidump.
-u, --full - create full core dump.
-d, --diag - enable diagnostic messages.
```

[Read more about createdump here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/botr/xplat-minidump-generation.md)

---

Another option is to use dotnet-dump global tool which [you can read about it here](https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/blob/master/documentation/dotnet-dump-instructions.md).

> On Linux, the runtime version must be 3.0 or greater. On Windows,
>   dotnet-dump collect will work with any version of the runtime.

Because I was running v2.2 then I was unable to use this tool.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `dotnet-dump` and friends? They support `mini` dumps, which are smaller and may be enough for what you need:

```
$ dotnet tool install -g dotnet-dump
You can invoke the tool using the following command: dotnet-dump
Tool 'dotnet-dump' (version '3.0.47001') was successfully installed.
$ dotnet dump collect --help
collect:
  Capture dumps from a process

Usage:
  dotnet-dump collect [options]

Options:
  --type <Heap|Mini>  The dump type determines the kinds of information that are collected from the process. There are two types: heap - A large and relatively comprehensive dump containing module lists, thread lists, all
                      stacks, exception information, handle information, and all memory except for mapped images. mini - A small dump containing module lists, thread lists, exception information and all stacks. If not
                      specified 'heap' is the default.
```

Comment: unfortunately this tool requires runtime v3 or greater, but I'm running 2.2.
btw maoni suggested createdump utility that worked. https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/botr/xplat-minidump-generation.md